# Google Search Console Sitemap Errors in redirects

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have a short url website with over 700.000 shorts urls in it. I have created sitemaps for these short urls which i have uploaded to Google Search Console. the short urls looks like the examples bellow and every short url looks like this. This is a niche site which only redirect to one specific site. The problem is that when i look in google Search Console i get a lot of "pages with errors". when i check these urls every url with an error exists and is active.

Why am i getting error from the sitemaps and how can i remove them / get them to get indexed properly ?

**Short url example**

```
htts://site.com/45za
htts://site.com/45xa
htts://site.com/41cf
```

Comment: These short redirects redirect externally, as opposed to redirecting to other URLs on your own site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correclty understand you've one site source (let's call it https://sourcesite.com) which has a lot of shortened url using an internal system, do shortened url look like :
https://sourcesite.com/short1
https://sourcesite.com/short2
https://sourcesite.com/short3

and those url redirect all to something like https://targetsite.com/longurl1 long2 and so on

So that understanding of search console is correct cause you link to an url which is not the final one, so Google detect a redirection.
in your case it's a external one.
linking to an URL who is not the final one is not a good practic because google has to perform to hit instead of one.

if those shortened url are responding only with a 301 code they won't be indexed. Google index only URL answering with a 200 code.